# WPF DataTrigger change control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, triggers

I have a `ListView` that is filled by an `ObservableCollection<MenuTrayItem>`. In my resources I've defined a `DataTemplate` for that class. I want to catch the trigger on the `ListViewItem` control and change the background of a `Border` control in my `DataTemplate`.

The error that I'm getting is

> `{"Child with Name 'Container' not found in VisualTree."}`

**GlobalResources.xaml**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuTrayItem_Template" DataType="{x:Type model:MenuTrayItem}">
    <view:MenuTrayItemView Margin="5,0,5,0" />

    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
            <!-- i am trying to change the background on the control "Container"
                 in the <view:MenuTrayitemView /> -->
            <Setter TargetName="Container" Property="Border.Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

**/Views/MenuTrayItemView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CellestusInvoicing.Views.MenuTrayItemView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/GlobalResources.xaml" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Border x:Name="Container" Width="64" Height="48" CornerRadius="5" Background="{StaticResource Gradient_Grey}" Cursor="Hand" MouseEnter="Container_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Container_MouseLeave">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image Margin="0,3,0,0" Width="60" Height="30" Source="{Binding Image, FallbackValue='/Images/Icons/MenuTray_Home.png'}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Title, FallbackValue='title'}" FontSize="10" Foreground="White" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The border is outside the scope of the setter.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.targetname.aspx):

> You can set this property to the name of any element within the scope of where the setter collection (the collection that this setter is part of) is applied. This is typically a named element that is within the template that contains this setter.

You could possibly place the trigger in the Style of the Border itself. looking for the ListViewItem from the inside. As this couples the UserControl to the use in ListViewItems that might not be wanted so you could also create an interface-property on the UserControl itself which is used by the DataTrigger which again will be on the Border but the property will be set from outside.

Comment: I understood that it was out of the scope, but I didn't know how to get to it. Can you give me an example of what you mean by body modify the UserControl to take it's DataContext into account? I have no idea...

Comment: Actually, scratch that, you already use the DataContext and the binding in the DataTrigger does not need it, i just mean that you should either make your border look outside via a RelativeSource binding to the ListViewItem or you create a new property on the usercontrol which will be used internally and set externally (since the UserControl itself is in scope).